# Проблема с чтением фалов по его пути

Tags: android, файлы

У моего приложения есть папка, в которой хранятся картинки, я заходил в папку с помощью менеджера, и они там действительно есть. Мне необходимо достать каждую картинку. Для этого я получаю список всех файлов, находящихся в данном каталоге, методом **File.listFiles();**, потом проверяю, что файлы он нашёл, и вывожу список всех файлов - он верный. Потом я использую метод **BitmapFactory.decodeFile();**, но тут выскакивает ошибка (**FileNotFoundException**), что файл не найден.

Помогите, чем сможете, уже час сижу и не могу найти решение. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: дайте код, как вы просматриваете список файлов, и полный код вызова BitmapFactory.decodeFile();

Comment: Повторю еще раз. Скорее всего, вы как-то неправильно вызываете BitmapFactory.decodeFile(); 
   
Покажите код.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы тестируете на Android 4.4+, то надо вам дополнительно прописать разрешение в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: И, кстати, именно из-за этого нововведения в API Level 19( Android KitKat ) в свое время было не мало головной боли и непонятных поначалу вылетов различных приложений. Поэтому всегда важно хотя бы поверхностно ознакомляться с новым API Level`ом!

Comment: Вы серьёзно?

У меня добавлены разрешения и на чтение и на запись (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`). 

Если бы не стояли эти разрешения, то выскочила бы фатальная ошибка и там ясно было бы написано, что проблема в разрешении и в каком конкретно. Тут проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, в какой папке лежат файлы?( полный путь )

Comment: data/data/com.example.olololo/files/